# Asp.Net MVC - Update live Web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, upgrade, app-offline.htm

What is the best way to update a live Web site created with Asp.Net MVC 2.0 ?

Using the app_offline.html used in Asp.Net ?

Other new way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC running on the top of ASP.NET `app_offline` still applies, so updating an ASP.NET MVC site is no different than updating a classic ASP.NET site.